# how do I embed a Ruby object in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, erb

I am trying to embed Ruby in the JS.erb file, where I want to be able to access the @user object and all its relations.

1. I do not want to convert to JSON object. I want the ERB to
   precompile on server-side.
2. I do not want to iterate in the view but in the JS file. How should
   i be structuring my controller/ view / js.erb file to make this
   work?

Controller - user_controller

```
 class UsersController < ApplicationController

      def index
      end

 end
```

Model - user.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :email, :first_name, :last_name
  has_many :qualification_rs
end
```

View - Users.html.erb is blank ( i want to purely get my code from JS)

```
<html>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Javascript asset - users.js.erb

```
$(document).ready(function(){
<% @users.each do |user| %> 
$('body').append(<% = user.first_name%>);
<%end%>
});
```

The following error appears

"undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass"
i.e. it does not recognize @users in the js file. (it does in the user.html.erb file from which i am including the javascript tag. What else do i do to get the instance object to be recognized within the js file?

Answer (score 1):

Use `<%=` and `%>` (and the ruby/rails doc)

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
      <% @users.each do |user| %> 
      $('body').append("<p><%= user.first_name %></p>");
      <%end%>
    });
```

Comment: "undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass"
i.e. not that i am not running the erb file on html but on the js file in the assets folder. it does not recognize @users in the js file. (it does in the user.html.erb file from which i am including the javascript tag. What else do i do to get the instance object to be recognized within the js file?

Comment: You need to instanciate it in your controller like `@user = User.find(1)` for example

Answer (score 0):

check for `@users` is present or not like following

```
  <% @users.each do |user| %> 
    $('body').append("<p><%= user.first_name %></p>");
  <% end if @users%>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure whether the question was too clear- here was the final resolution.

I finally had to include within   tags the piece of JS within Users.html.erb instead of including the JS as a separate file within assets/ public.

The @ users variable is accessible directly only in the HTML file within the views folder and not from the assets directories directly.